# How to Trigger Function in Multiple Child-Component from Parent in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is parent Vue(simplified)

```
<template>
 <form>
  <password-text-field />
  <password-text-field />

  <v-btn @click="clearForm"</v-btn>
 </form>
</template>
...
methods: {
clearForm () {
  this.$refs.PasswordTextField.clearField()
 }
}
```

in child;

```
created: function () {
    this.$on('clearField', this.clearField)
  },
methods: {
    clearField () {
      this.password = ''
    }
```

When I click the button in parent Vue, only the second child-component triggers the function. First one doesn't. How should I try to fix this ?

Comment: This would probably help you: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: You can use EventBus to emit clearField event from parent and listen in all children.